# How do I implement hook_views_post_execute

Tags: 8, hooks

I am attempting to modify the output of view programmatically using hook_views_post_execute.

I created the usual module structure (in this case using drupal generate:module.

I am able to use other hooks (such as hook_entity_view)successfully.

However, hook_views_post_execute causes blows up the website with the message

> The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.

The code block is right out of api.drupal.org.

```
/**
 * @param ViewExecutable $view
 */
function idm_views_post_execute(ViewExecutable $view) {

  // If there are more than 100 results, show a message that encourages the user
  // to change the filter settings.
  // (This action could be performed later in the execution process, but not
  // earlier.)
  $temp = $view;

  if ($view->total_rows > 100) {
    \Drupal::messenger()
      ->addStatus(t('You have more than 100 hits. Use the filter settings to narrow down your list.'));
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to provide the actual error so people can help. Otherwise all we can do is guess. Did you include the `use` statement for `ViewExecutable`?

Comment: No, it exists: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21views.api.php/function/hook_views_post_execute/8.6.x

Comment: Also note the comment on that page: `Please note that this hook is not being called on the second request if (page) caching is active, even if view cache is disabled!`

Comment: @kevin. Thanks for the quick reply.  The actual error was as indicated.  White screen on the web browser with the words. "The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later."

I have no idea what you mean by "include the use statement"  I suspect it's something simple like that though!

Comment: That isn't an error... its just an output saying an error happened. An error trace would tell you what the problem is.

Comment: @sea26.2 turn on error reporting by adding `$config['system.logging']['error_level'] = 'verbose';` to your settings.php. OR if you have [drupal console](https://drupalconsole.com/) use `drupal site:mode dev` and to turn it off `drupal site:mode prod`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is you did not include the `use` statement at the top of your file that tells the application how to locate the class `ViewExecutable`. This is a PHP construct and not Drupal specific, which is why it is not always mentioned explicitly in the documentation.

At the top of your file, add:

`use Drupal\views\ViewExecutable;`

The incoming argument to the hook is of type `ViewExecutable`, but PHP does not know how to find that class, so it errors out unless you either use the `use` statement, or change the function signature to:

```
function idm_views_post_execute(Drupal\views\ViewExecutable $view)
```

Clear cache and reload. If the error persists, you'll need to provide log(s) to indicate what the actual error that occurred was.

If you copied and pasted the code here for `hook_entity_view` that would explain why that worked for you:

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_entity_view/8.6.x

The example here has the full path in the argument list.

```
hook_entity_view(array &$build, \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface $entity, \Drupal\Core\Entity\Display\EntityViewDisplayInterface $display, $view_mode)
```

Comment: You're awesome. I'm far to used to the old ways of Drupal 6 and 7.  

Added the "use" statement per your suggestion and problem is solved

Comment: The docs should be consistent in this manner, I would agree. Consider grabbing an editor like PHPStorm to help you wade into new territory - it would have caught this for you.

Comment: Actually, I just made the switch from Komodo IDE to PhpStorm...
But, it either didn't catch it, or I didn't see it screaming at me

Comment: Did you set up the Drupal/Symfony plug-ins and set the language level to 7.0? Spend some time with it, these things will open up.